# Xamarin Can't Connect to SQL Database

Tags: c#, android, sql-server, xamarin.android

I have a C# Xamarin Android application which I need to connect to a SQL Server instance accessible over the network.

```
try
{
      using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
      {
                cn.Open();

                IsConnected = true;
       }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
        Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Error Occuerred: " + ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
   }
```

The Connection String is as follows: Data Source=IPAddress;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=SomeUser;Password=SomePassword

I have included the INTERNET and WIFI_State Permissions in the manifest. (To check if wifi is currently turned on and connected to some kind on network)

I am getting an error: Server Does Not Exist or Connection is refused.
I can connect my Honeywell Scanning device to the database with the same connection string.

Please NOTE I don not want a web service to handle the SQL connection in order for me to select and update tables.

Comment: Is there only 1 sql instance on given IP? Is this instance port set to 1433? If the previous dont hold you have to explicity set instance name and port on Data Source, like "Data Source=IP\instanceName,port

Comment: For example the database is found on 192.168.8.100:1433 (1433 default SQL Server port which i opened to TCP and UPD connections) and the Initial Catalog points to the correct database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote an ASP. NET web service which is very efficient and quick